# Some File not found when publish to azure web app

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-web-app-service, face-api

I am created a HTML file and some js/css etc, and to publish to azure. It's only a single page web page. But after publish I got error, some files not found.

[image]

Missing file is I get from

https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Face-Detection-JavaScript/blob/master/models/face_landmark_68_model-shard1

It's working fine in local. The same issue I get when I use json files. So I just added in web config,

```
   <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
 </staticContent>
```

then json files are working fine. Any idea what I missing?

Comment: Is the route specified? Do you have [static files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files) enabled?

Comment: It's only html file, not using core. Then how can I enable static files?

Comment: You tagged it with `asp.net-mvc`. Where are you hosting it? Have a look at using [static website hosting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website) and see what happens there.

Comment: published in azure

Comment: May I know if my answer helps ?

Comment: I tried <mimeMap fileExtension="" mimeType="application/octstream" />. now its working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you do not change any thing when creating the web app, your web app would be running on ASP.NET platform. Then, the contents under folder models will not be served.

So, my suggestions:

1. You can use Azure Storage to host your single-page website.  we have a tutorial for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website
2. You can choose to use Java platform and use Tomcat as the server. Then there will be no problem.[image]